# post and update value of checkbox using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

based on my yesterday post [how to update and post the value of checkbox from ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813748/how-to-update-and-post-the-value-of-checkbox-from-ajax-call)  i changed my code to this i.e

```
$query="select * from student";
$result=mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<tr>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rs['st_id']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rs['name']"; ?></td>
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="checked" onclick="UpdateCheckBox()" <?php if($rs['checked']==1){echo "checked"; } ?> /></td>
<td align="center"><a href="delete_student.php?id="><img src="images/delete_icon.png" alt="Delete" /></a></td>
<td align="center"><a href="update_student.php?id="><img src="images/update.png" alt="Update" /></a></td>
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
    function UpdateCheckBox()
{
   var st_id = <?php echo $rs['st_id']; ?>;
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var chkName = $(this).attr('name');
    var checkVal = $(':checkbox[name='+chkName+']').attr('checked');//true or false
    $.ajax({
      url: 'update.php?checboxName=' + checkVal,//Do update on server-side
      success: function(data) {
        alert('Updated successful.');
      }
    });
  });
}
    </script>
  <?php
  }

   ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

my update.php code is

```
$conn=new LoginSystem();
$conn->connect();
$update=$_GET['checboxName'];
$sql="UPDATE student SET checked='$update'";
$rs=mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

when i clicked on the checkbox nothing is happen and when refresh the whole page it is automatically unchecked.
Note that there is no form or submit button all thing is done on checkbox on click event. I want to update the database by clicking on checkbox in populated table.
any help please

Comment: You've successfully copied and pasted someone's answer, but you haven't learned what it does, you haven't identified the mistakes in that person's answer, and you haven't written any server-side code to make use of their client-side code.

Comment: Your newly posted update.php code updates every single row in the table, and sets its checked column to the name of one checkbox. I think you need to buy a beginners PHP & MySQL book. You're not ready for this yet and getting little tidbits of info from Q&A here is not going to give you the mental framework you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell you why `update.php` isn't working since you didn't share that code. Right now, it can't possibly work, as you're not providing it with any way to know what row to update and whether the box was checked or not.

You need to give the checkboxes in each row different names so that you know which one was checked in your PHP code. Use the row's identifier in the name, like `checkbox_3` or `checkbox[3]`. Then you need to make sure you make the checkbox's value part of the URL as well.

Comment: Now i update my question as you said that to give the checkboxes in each row different names but the checkbox is come from mysql table dynamically should i give the name as an array....

Comment: Give the checkboxes different values, not different names.

Comment: I already answered this. No David, that is no more correct. Both ways will get the row identifier to PHP.

Comment: i give the value as value="<?php echo $rs['st_id'];?>" so that each row is identified with a unique value but still not work\

Comment: You need to write code to USE This value, just changing your HTML writes neither the JavaScript nor the PHP for you.

Comment: could you please help me in this script cause cant understand any thing about jquery or ajax

Comment: If you can't understand the process, you can't write this application. If you want other people to write it for you, you post this as a freelance job on an appropriate site, and HIRE a developer.